# How to re-render parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

parent component has a p tag which animate it's inner text. animation works when i refresh the page.

here is the Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends Component {
    rerender=()=>{
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p className='animate-left'>Animation</p>
                <Child rerender={this.rerender}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

here is the Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends Component {
    clickHandler=()=>{
        this.props.rerender()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

i want to animate again/ re-render parent component by clicking the button of child component.
How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide `animate-left` in detail?

Comment: @Yung-DaLinLynda, i'm using a css framework named 'W3.CSS'. i remove 'w3-' from the class name. There is no problem in css. when i refresh the page the animation works well. but when i click the button it don't work. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_ref_animate-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have `state` in the parent component and pass down this state to the child component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }
  rerender = () => {
    this.forceUpdate();
  };
  forceUpdate = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      counter: state.counter + 1
    }));
  };
  render() {
    console.log("got rendered");
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="animate-left" key={this.state.counter}>Animation</p>
        <Child rerender={this.rerender} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

and in the child component update this state:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  clickHandler = () => {
    this.props.rerender();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: it don't work. but when i click the button, console.log print **got rendered** but animation don't work

Comment: What is the content of `animate-left` class?

Comment: .animate-left{position:relative;animation:animateleft 0.4s}@keyframes animateleft{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}

Comment: to force the animation add `key={this.state.counter}` to the `p` tag i will edit my answer.